# Angular 2 Click + ngClass, how to apply ONLY to SELF but not ALL elements inside ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng-class, ngfor

In Angular 1.x
this following code works as I want to to click and flip a card inside an ng-repeat

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="let card of cards">
<div class="flipcard" ng-class="{'flipped':isflipped}" ng-click="isflipped = !isflipped">
</div>
</div>
```

However in Angular 2
when clicked, it flipped every "card" inside the ngFor loop... how do I bind the ngClass condition to the element itself only?

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let card of cards">
<div class="flipcard"  [ngClass]="{'flipped': isflipped }" (click)="isflipped = !isflipped;">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <div class="flipcard"  [ngClass]="{'flipped': card.isflipped }" (click)="card.isflipped = !card.isflipped;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked!!
I guess Angular 2 is less forgiving as Angular 1.x so the behaviour is different? it's a good thing for me to learn better practice in coding.

Answer (score 4):

### Why does it work with AngularJS (1.x) ?

`ng-repeat` create a new scope for each iterated element, so the `isFlipped` property is set on the iterated element scope (unique for each element):

> ## [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)
>
> The `ngRepeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and `$index` is set to the item index or key.

### Why is it not working with Angular (2+) ?

Angular has no scope anymore, so when you set the `isFlipped` property, it is on the current component, not anything related to the iterated element.

#### If `card` elements are Objects :

For your particular case, it seems that every card is an Object, so you can just add a a property `isFlipped` to every `card` element like @Harry Ninh suggests it. **Think to declare this property inside the class or interface that defines `card` elements** otherwise AOT compilation might fail.

If you don't want to add a contextual property onto your class/interface, see the "If there can be more than one flipped card(...)" part.

#### If there can be only one flipped card :

If you can only have one single flipped card, you can add a property `currentCard` to your component and compare the iterated card to the current one  inside your template :

**component :**

```
export class MyComponent{
    // (...)
    currentCard:Card;
    // (...)
}
```

**template :**

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <div class="flipcard"  [ngClass]="{'flipped': card===currentCard }" (click)="currentCard = card">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### If there can be more than one flipped card and `card` elements are not objects or can be null.

Well in this case you need to maintain the state flipped/ not flipped of each item, like using an array of boolean or an Object with `card` value as key and boolean values

**component :**

```
export class MyComponent{

    // (...)

    cards: Card=[];
    private flipped: boolean[];

    flip(index:number){
      this.flipped[index]=!this.flipped[index]
    }

    // (...)

}
```

**template :**

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let card of cards: let i= index">
    <div class="flipcard"  [ngClass]="{'flipped': flipped[i] }" (click)="flip(i)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer and explanation

Comment: In my case, in the function that flips I add an extra property to the to the object and then check what is its value. I got that inspiration from your Angular 2 part, thanks.