# Angular 4 Click + ngClass, how to apply ONLY to SELF but not ALL elements inside ngFor

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 when I clicked the button, it added class "newstyle" every "button" inside the ngFor loop... how do I bind the ngClass condition to the element itself only?

```
<button [ngClass]="{'newstyle': isClicked }" (click)=" isClicked = !isClicked">Click button</button>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does your `for` loop look like? Can you create some conditions inside it which will satisfy only your single button you want to apply the class style ?

Comment: My question is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565002/angular-2-click-ngclass-how-to-apply-only-to-self-but-not-all-elements-inside

But the new answer is not working on Angular 4. And I dont know why:

<button [ngClass]="{'newstyle': button.isClicked }" (click)=" button.isClicked = !button.isClicked">Click button</button>

Comment: I added a more generic answer to the question you posted in your comment because the accepted one was very low quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button *ngFor="let thing of things" [class.newstyle]="currentThing === thing" (click)="currentThing = thing">Click button</button>
```

And you have to add currentThing as a property of your component's class:

```
export YourComponent {
    currentThing: any;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Did you know how to do the same with *ngIf?
Example: <h1 *ngIf="showHide">
<button (click)="showHide = !showHide">

Comment: <button *ngFor="let thing of things; let i = index"  (click)="isShown[i] = !isShown[i]">Click button</button>

export YourComponent {
    isShown: boolean[];
}

Comment: @TwikssPower, see `*ngIf` in my answer too: `<label *ngIf="item.isClicked">Item was Clicked: {{item.id}}</label>`. Can be applied in same manner to any html element. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A similat UseCase: iterate through collection and apply a specific class `item-updated` for `items` in `collection` which were edited.
*This part is optional, just for demo: `[attr.title]="item.isDirty  ? 'Item was updated' : null"`*

**html component**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of collection">
    <label>Name: {{item.name}}</label>
    <button class="btn"
         [ngClass]="{'item-updated' : item.isDirty}"
         [attr.title]="item.isDirty ? 'Item was updated' : null">
     Save
    </button>
</div>
```

**Explanations:**
 Only when the `item.isDirty` condition is matched, the button will receive the specific class.

In your case, from question, all your buttons are binded to the same `isClicked` property. So, does not matter which one is edited, your property changes, and all other buttons receive the newest class.

**EDIT:**
*The code snippet from question:*

```
<button [ngClass]="{'newstyle': isClicked }" (click)=" isClicked = !isClicked">Click button</button>
```

**Transformed**

**HTML component**

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of yourArray">
        <label *ngIf="item.isClicked">Item was Clicked: {{item.id}}</label>
        <button [ngClass]="{'newStyle' : !item.isClicked}" (click)="changeItemState(item)">Click button </button>
    </div>
```

**TS component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-component',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html'  
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    public yourArray: any[];

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.yourArray = [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'First',
                isClicked: false;
            }, 
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Second',
                isClicked: false;
            }, 
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Third',
                isClicked: true;
            }, 
        ];
    }

    public changeItemState(item: any): void {
        item.isClicked = !item.isClicked;
    }
}
```