# Angular 4 toggle fontawesome button inside ngFor

Tags: html, angular, api, typescript

I realise this might be a duplicate of
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565002/angular-2-click-ngclass-how-to-apply-only-to-self-but-not-all-elements-inside) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017246/angular2-toggle-icons-inside-ngfor), but i've gotten blind to this. Im getting my data from a rest api as an object, which contains number of votes.
The toggle function works on all the fontawesome icons, and not just the specific ones, even though the counters are working fine.
I want the filled heart icon to be toggled on the specific story, when the icon has been pressed. Vice versa when it's been pressed again.

I'm using angular4 and fontawesome 5.

The data is from an observable in my service.

Component:

```
private vote(story) {
    this.liked = !this.liked; //heart filled
    if (story.userVote == false) {
      this.storiesService.voteStory(story.objectID)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log("Added upvote")
          story.votes++;            //api counter
          console.log(story.votes)
          story.userVote = true;    //api call
        })
    } else if (story.userVote == true) {
      this.storiesService.unVoteStory(story.objectID)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log("Removed upvote")
          story.votes--;
          console.log(story.votes)
          story.userVote = false;
        })
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <a (click)="vote(story)" style="font-size: 13px;" *ngIf="!liked" matTooltip="Like story" matTooltipPosition="above"><i class="far fa-heart"></i> {{ story.votes || 0 }} </a>
  <a (click)="vote(story)" style="font-size: 13px;" *ngIf="liked" matTooltip="Like story" matTooltipPosition="above"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> {{ story.votes || 0 }} </a>
```

Comment: Can you explain what the exact issue is?

Comment: Yes, i want the filled heart icon to be toggled on the specific story, when the icon has been pressed. Vice versa when it's been pressed again. `this.liked = true` or false

Comment: The issue is, that it toggles every single icon on the page

Comment: I've added pictures

Comment: what are these different classes 'far' and 'fas' shouldn't it be like `'fa fa-heart'` and `'fa fa-heart-o'`?

Comment: No, im using fontawesome 5 - basically the same, but some edited name conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.liked` refers to the `liked` property in the component. You'll have to toggle/store a `liked` property for every separate `story`. Otherwise, toggling `this.liked` to `true`/`false` will set the property for the whole component, therefore it will be `true`/`false` for every `*ngIf` at the same time.

What you need to do is something along the lines of this:

```
<a (click)="vote(story)" style="font-size: 13px;" *ngIf="!story.liked" matTooltip="Like story" matTooltipPosition="above"><i class="far fa-heart"></i> {{ story.votes || 0 }} </a>
<a (click)="vote(story)" style="font-size: 13px;" *ngIf="story.liked" matTooltip="Like story" matTooltipPosition="above"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> {{ story.votes || 0 }} </a>
```

And toggle it like so:

```
private vote(story) {
    story.liked = !story.liked;
    //Cut for brevity
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked with the API data! Marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) (and only one icon tag) instead of this ngIf to toggle the fas/far class?

```
<i ngClass="{'fa-heart': true, 'far': !liked, 'fas': liked }">
```

Comment: +1 for making the obvious suggestion although it doesn't actually answer their question, they probably still need to use `story.liked` as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

So i used the userVote boolean in my api, and ended up like this:

Component:

```
private vote(story) {
    if (story.userVote == false) {
      story.userVote = !story.userVote; //heart filled
      ....
}
```

HTML:

```
<a (click)="vote(story)" style="font-size: 13px;" *ngIf="story.userVote===false" matTooltip="Like story" matTooltipPosition="above"><i class="far fa-heart"></i> {{ story.votes || 0 }} </a>
<a (click)="vote(story)" style="font-size: 13px;" *ngIf="story.userVote" matTooltip="Like story" matTooltipPosition="above"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> {{ story.votes || 0 }} </a>
```